# Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

**ORA-00942: table or view does not exist: After Update Spring Boot from 
           1.4.9 to 2.0.9 and Hibernate to 5.2.18.FINAL**

WHen i use via entity manager it works but when i try to fetch via 
 JPA Repository then it throws this error. Will anybody help me out?
 I have used following dependencies

```
      <hibernate.version>5.2.18.Final</hibernate.version>

      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>

     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>

    <dependency>
          <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc</groupId>
          <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
          <version>12.2.0.1</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

My JPAConfig.java

```
         @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "embedded", havingValue = "true", 
         matchIfMissing = true)
         @Configuration
         @RefreshScope
         @EnableTransactionManagement
         @EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", 
         transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager", basePackages = {
            "kgfsl" })
         public class JPAConfig {

        @Bean
        public Validator getValidator() {
            return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        }

        @Value("${db.url}")
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.100.1.95:1539:HFSL12C";

        @Value("${db.driverClassName}")
        String dbDriverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";

        @Value("${db.userName}")
        String dbUserName = "QARMSV2";

        @Value("${db.password}")
        String dbPassword = "QARMSV2";

        @Value("${db.databaseType}")
        String dbDatabaseType = "Oracle";

        @Value("${encryptionOn:false}")
        private boolean encryptionOn;

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @RefreshScope
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(dbDriverClassName);
            dataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
            dataSource.setUsername(dbUserName);
            if (encryptionOn)
                dataSource.setPassword(CryptoUtil.decrypt(dbPassword));
            else
                dataSource.setPassword(dbPassword);
            return dataSource;
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        @RefreshScope
        public Map<String, Object> jpaProperties() {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
            props.put("hibernate.dialect", 
           ApplicationStartUpFactory.getDialect(dbDatabaseType));       
            props.put("javax.persistence.validation.mode", "none");
            props.put("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");  
            //props.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", 
           "org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl");
            // 
            props.put("hibernate.ejb.interceptor",
            "kgfsl.framework.config.AuditColumnWiseInterceptor");
            return props;
            }



            public static int batchSize() {
            return Integer.valueOf(Dialect.DEFAULT_BATCH_SIZE);
            }

           @Primary
           @Bean
           public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new 
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false); 
            hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.
            setDatabase(ApplicationStartUpFactory.getJPAVendor(dbDatabaseType));
            return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
            }

           @Primary
           @Bean
           public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
            return new 
           JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
            }

          @Bean
          @Primary
          public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
            entityManagerFactory() {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new 
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            lef.setDataSource(this.dataSource());
            lef.setJpaPropertyMap(this.jpaProperties());
            lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(this.jpaVendorAdapter());

            // lef.setPackagesToScan("hfsl");
            String entityPackages = "hfsl.*.*";
            lef.setPackagesToScan(entityPackages.split(","));
            lef.setPersistenceUnitName("default"); // <- giving 'default' 
           as name

            return lef;
            }

            @Bean()
            @Qualifier("jdbcTemplate")
            public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
            return new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource());
            }

        @Bean(name = "namedParameterJdbcTemplate")
        public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
            return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(this.dataSource());
          }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private DatabasePopulator createDatabasePopulator() {
            ResourceDatabasePopulator databasePopulator = new 
           ResourceDatabasePopulator();
            databasePopulator.setContinueOnError(false);
            /*
             * if (new ClassPathResource("basic_table.sql").exists())
             * databasePopulator.addScript(new 
         ClassPathResource("basic_table.sql"));
             */
            return databasePopulator;
           }

           @Bean
           @Primary
           public PhysicalNamingStrategy physical() {
            return new PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl();
            }

          @Bean
          @Primary
          public ImplicitNamingStrategy implicit() {
            return new ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl ();
          }
          }
```

I Have Following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1054)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:623)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:252)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:612)
at 

oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:226)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:59)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:747)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:904)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1082)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3780)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1343)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3822)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
    ... 161 more
Caused by: Error : 942, Position : 1387, Sql = select client0_.CLIENT_CODE as CLIENT_CODE1_63_, client0_.createdAt as createdAt2_63_, client0_.createdBy as createdBy3_63_, client0_.active as active4_63_, client0_.approvedAt as approvedAt5_63_, client0_.approvedBy as approvedBy6_63_, client0_.modifiedAt as modifiedAt7_63_, client0_.modifiedBy as modifiedBy8_63_, client0_.AREA as AREA9_63_, client0_.BUILDING as BUILDING10_63_, client0_.CATEGORY_CODE as CATEGORY_CODE11_63_, client0_.CITY as CITY12_63_, client0_.CLIENT_CREATED_FROM as CLIENT_CREATED_FR13_63_, client0_.CLIENT_TYPE as CLIENT_TYPE14_63_, client0_.COUNTRY as COUNTRY15_63_, client0_.EMAIL_ID as EMAIL_ID16_63_, client0_.IS_ERROR as IS_ERROR17_63_, client0_.FAX_NO as FAX_NO18_63_, client0_.FULL_NAME as FULL_NAME19_63_, client0_.GLOBAL_REF_ID as GLOBAL_REF_ID20_63_, client0_.id as id21_63_, client0_.MOBILE_NO as MOBILE_NO22_63_, client0_.NAME as NAME23_63_, client0_.PAN_NO as PAN_NO24_63_, client0_.IS_PARENT as IS_PARENT25_63_, client0_.PARENT_CODE as PARENT_CODE26_63_, client0_.PHONE_NO as PHONE_NO27_63_, client0_.PIN_CODE as PIN_CODE28_63_, client0_.PRIORITY_TYPE as PRIORITY_TYPE29_63_, client0_.IS_PROP as IS_PROP30_63_, client0_.REMARK as REMARK31_63_, client0_.SEBI_REG_EXPIRY_DATE as SEBI_REG_EXPIRY_D32_63_, client0_.SEBI_REG_NO as SEBI_REG_NO33_63_, client0_.STATE as STATE34_63_, client0_.STREET as STREET35_63_, client0_.USER_ID as USER_ID36_63_ from M_CLIENT client0_, OriginalSql = select client0_.CLIENT_CODE as CLIENT_CODE1_63_, client0_.createdAt as createdAt2_63_, client0_.createdBy as createdBy3_63_, client0_.active as active4_63_, client0_.approvedAt as approvedAt5_63_, client0_.approvedBy as approvedBy6_63_, client0_.modifiedAt as modifiedAt7_63_, client0_.modifiedBy as modifiedBy8_63_, client0_.AREA as AREA9_63_, client0_.BUILDING as BUILDING10_63_, client0_.CATEGORY_CODE as CATEGORY_CODE11_63_, client0_.CITY as CITY12_63_, client0_.CLIENT_CREATED_FROM as CLIENT_CREATED_FR13_63_, client0_.CLIENT_TYPE as CLIENT_TYPE14_63_, client0_.COUNTRY as COUNTRY15_63_, client0_.EMAIL_ID as EMAIL_ID16_63_, client0_.IS_ERROR as IS_ERROR17_63_, client0_.FAX_NO as FAX_NO18_63_, client0_.FULL_NAME as FULL_NAME19_63_, client0_.GLOBAL_REF_ID as GLOBAL_REF_ID20_63_, client0_.id as id21_63_, client0_.MOBILE_NO as MOBILE_NO22_63_, client0_.NAME as NAME23_63_, client0_.PAN_NO as PAN_NO24_63_, client0_.IS_PARENT as IS_PARENT25_63_, client0_.PARENT_CODE as PARENT_CODE26_63_, client0_.PHONE_NO as PHONE_NO27_63_, client0_.PIN_CODE as PIN_CODE28_63_, client0_.PRIORITY_TYPE as PRIORITY_TYPE29_63_, client0_.IS_PROP as IS_PROP30_63_, client0_.REMARK as REMARK31_63_, client0_.SEBI_REG_EXPIRY_DATE as SEBI_REG_EXPIRY_D32_63_, client0_.SEBI_REG_NO as SEBI_REG_NO33_63_, client0_.STATE as STATE34_63_, client0_.STREET as STREET35_63_, client0_.USER_ID as USER_ID36_63_ from M_CLIENT client0_, Error Msg = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
    ... 176 more
```

Comment: do you have a table **M_CLIENT** in  database

Comment: a message at the bottom gives a line starting with `Caused by: Error : 942, Position : 1387` mentioning about the root cause and tells that the table(the name of the table should be after `M_CLIENT` or just after the excerpt `M_CLIENT client0_,`) doesn't exists(e.g.not reachable from your currently connected user).

Comment: most like you have not annotated your entity with table name,  can tell us your actual table name and respective entity

Comment: Yes i have a Table M_CLIENT- Everything is fine before update. After update springboot and hibernate only make this error.

Comment: Respective Entity is Client -@Entity
@Table(name = "M_CLIENT")
public class Client

Comment: Past two days i struggled with this error . Please help me out

Comment: did you execute generate the query , which is in exception trace on SQL client?

Comment: when using database client make sure you connect with QARMSV2/QARMSV2

Comment: Do you mean show SQL? yes, when I am connecting via entity manager I can access the schema without error. but when I access it via JPA Repository it throws the error

Comment: posted as answer because the content was more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couldn't paste in the comment as your query is long, some debugging steps

1. **Connect to a database using SQL plus (oracle client) or Toad**
2. **connect using QARMSV2/QARMSV2**
3. **Executed the below query**
4. **If your query works execute the same program plain JDBC program**

> select client0_.CLIENT_CODE as CLIENT_CODE1_63_, client0_.createdAt
>   as createdAt2_63_, client0_.createdBy as createdBy3_63_,
>   client0_.active as active4_63_, client0_.approvedAt as
>   approvedAt5_63_, client0_.approvedBy as approvedBy6_63_,
>   client0_.modifiedAt as modifiedAt7_63_, client0_.modifiedBy as
>   modifiedBy8_63_, client0_.AREA as AREA9_63_, client0_.BUILDING as
>   BUILDING10_63_, client0_.CATEGORY_CODE as CATEGORY_CODE11_63_,
>   client0_.CITY as CITY12_63_, client0_.CLIENT_CREATED_FROM as
>   CLIENT_CREATED_FR13_63_, client0_.CLIENT_TYPE as CLIENT_TYPE14_63_,
>   client0_.COUNTRY as COUNTRY15_63_, client0_.EMAIL_ID as
>   EMAIL_ID16_63_, client0_.IS_ERROR as IS_ERROR17_63_, client0_.FAX_NO
>   as FAX_NO18_63_, client0_.FULL_NAME as FULL_NAME19_63_,
>   client0_.GLOBAL_REF_ID as GLOBAL_REF_ID20_63_, client0_.id as
>   id21_63_, client0_.MOBILE_NO as MOBILE_NO22_63_, client0_.NAME as
>   NAME23_63_, client0_.PAN_NO as PAN_NO24_63_, client0_.IS_PARENT as
>   IS_PARENT25_63_, client0_.PARENT_CODE as PARENT_CODE26_63_,
>   client0_.PHONE_NO as PHONE_NO27_63_, client0_.PIN_CODE as
>   PIN_CODE28_63_, client0_.PRIORITY_TYPE as PRIORITY_TYPE29_63_,
>   client0_.IS_PROP as IS_PROP30_63_, client0_.REMARK as REMARK31_63_,
>   client0_.SEBI_REG_EXPIRY_DATE as SEBI_REG_EXPIRY_D32_63_,
>   client0_.SEBI_REG_NO as SEBI_REG_NO33_63_, client0_.STATE as
>   STATE34_63_, client0_.STREET as STREET35_63_, client0_.USER_ID as
>   USER_ID36_63_ from M_CLIENT client0_

Comment: It executed successfully in Toad

Comment: ok now try with JDBC, I have a suspicion that you are not connected with the correct schema

Comment: what is schema name

Comment: QARMSV2 is schema name

Comment: When i connect with JDBC it works but via JPA again it throws the same error

Comment: ok add this line **dataSource.setSchema("QARMSV2")** in  dataSource() method also try with plain jdbc program

Comment: entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(LimitMonitorAdmin.class).list() - this query works but jpa only makes me the problem.. ok once i add that prop and let you know

Comment: if one query works with same schema and other doesn't then we need to rely on database error, change the table in same flow and map to different identical table/copy table and see\

Comment: Class Name : org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect
Method Name : convertHibernateAccessException
Line Number : 240

Comment: didn't understand last message ?

Comment: Thank for your continuous support. I hope the error is related to JPA Configurations Because all other types of a query can hit the schema except using JPA Repository

Comment: I am Connected with wrong schema. i have two schemas with two configurations . Atlast i found second schema was override the default schema . So only the error arises.. Thank You so much...  Shailesh Chandra

Comment: glad to know, to start with I had suspicion on the schema :)

Comment: can anyone answer for this similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747937/multiple-database-configuration-for-spring-data-jpa-2-0-9-release